# How to use the textblock operator in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to write informations of what my script is doing in the textblock. I have the Python script to call it but I don't know how to put text in it:

`bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()`

What is the code to write "Hello world!" inside?

Answer (score 3):

An example using simple operator template, the 'REGISTER' option in bl_options set which among other things makes sure "bpy.ops.object.simple_operator" makes its way into the report created by bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock().

A call to [self.report(type, message)](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator%20report#bpy.types.Operator.report) writes to the report area, when run from UI.  For an [Operator report](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator%20report#bpy.types.Operator.report) 
 The type can be set of one of ('DEBUG', 'INFO', 'OPERATOR', 'PROPERTY', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT', 'ERROR_INVALID_CONTEXT', 'ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY')

```
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Hello World")
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

After running the simple operator, then ui.reports_to_textblock(),  the "Recent Reports" textblock will contain,

```
Operator: bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
Info: Hello World
```

In case you want to to open a [textblock](http:///www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.Text.html#bpy.types.Text) to write reports to, use API methods, `textblock` below is of type [`Text`](http:///www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.Text.html#bpy.types.Text)

```
import bpy

textblock = bpy.data.texts.get("RM_Report")

if not textblock:
    textblock = bpy.data.texts.new("RM_Report")

textblock.write("Hello World\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have copy/pasted your code but the textblock doesnt shows up near the render engine selection.