# How to read all ‘recent reports’ from info window

Tags: python

I think I know how to make a report that contains information from the info window.
I think the report is saved in a textblock called ‘recent reports’.

My question. How do I read the textblock, or how do I ‘print’ the textblock, or how do I save a file of ‘recent reports’?

I have read:
[How do I get the Info window's log text with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62360/how-do-i-get-the-info-windows-log-text-with-python)

[How to use the textblock operator in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55933/how-to-use-the-textblock-operator-in-python)

https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-from-info-panel/700032/2

Comment: Do you want a script that simply saves the contents of the INFO window to a file?

Comment: @rob Yes I want a script that simply saves the contents of the INFO window to a file. Even better, I would like a file that contained all the current settings to a file. I want to try different settings in Blender and have a readable record of the settings that were used.

Answer (score 3):

**Recent Reports**

Modifying code from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62620/15543

The code in answer prints the textblock.

This one removes all other recent reports from blend file, creates a new one via operator,  and writes it to filepath

```
import bpy


#remove other Recent Reports
reports = [bpy.data.texts.remove(t, do_unlink=True) 
           for t in bpy.data.texts
           if t.name.startswith("Recent Reports")]
# make a report
bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()
# save the report to file

filepath = "recent_reports.txt"
with open(filepath, "a") as f:
    f.write(bpy.data.texts["Recent Reports"].as_string())
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to clean up others, the new text added by operator can be found using sets.

```
import bpy

texts = set(bpy.data.texts)
bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()
new_text = (set(bpy.data.texts) - texts).pop()
filepath = "recent_reports.txt"
with open(filepath, "a") as f:
    f.write(new_text.as_string())
```

*both write to a file "recent_reports.txt" in the same folder blender was opened*

Comment: That works for me up until
# save the report to file.

The f-string needs Python 3.6
Blender 2.79 comes with Python 3.5 so I need the code without the f.

Please.

Comment: do you get an error or can not find the resulting file?

Comment: @PaulStGeorge I get a file named "recent_reports.txt" in the folder I started blender. I have write permission to that folder.  Edit filepath to a folder that you can write to.  What f-string?  Surely `with open(...) as f:` predates 3.5... anyway it is just simple text file io.  Change to suit your python version if need-be.

Comment: ... oh and don't  edit the filepath using  f-string formatting.

Comment: If there is an error message, copy it in system console, then paste the message here.  Make a filepath to a folder you can find. @rob does it work for you?

Comment: The first script gives `Unexpected EOF while parsing f.write(bpy.data.texts["Recent Reports"].as_string()` and the second
I get a clear `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'recent_reports.txt'` which is what I would expect.

Comment: setting the path to `c:\\myfolder\\recent_reports.txt` worked fine and the file contained all the Info window contents.

Comment: Now I have done this: 'Edit filepath to a folder that you can write to.', it all works perfectly.

Comment: @rob the first error it would appear that the operator hasn't finished writing before reading the text block. The recent reports op is a strange beast, I noticed when running it from console that console pipes the  stdout till the op is finished.  Might need to sleep.  Runs fine for me on linux.  (and I start blender from the terminal, re the permission errors) Cheers for the heads up.

Comment: @batFINGER `bpy.ops.ui.reports_to_textblock()` seems not be valid anymore for blender >2.81. Thus, is there any alternative to access the info log window and get the last reported info?

Comment: If you track down the operator, code  chances are it gleaned its info from window manager operators collection https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218706/15543  or the info window.

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I leave this here since in the last version the above solution is not anymore valid. Code snippet:

```
import bpy

def GetMacro(name):
    if name.startswith("bpy.ops"):
        try:
            return eval(name.split("(")[0] + ".get_rna_type().name")
        except:
            return name
    elif name.startswith('bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null)'):
        return True
    elif name.startswith('bpy.context'):
        split = name.split('=')
        if len(split) > 1:
            return split[0].split('.')[-1] + " = " + split[1]
        else:
            return ".".join(split[0].split('.')[-2:])
    else:
        return None
    
def getlastoperation(data, i=-1):
    if len(data) <= 1:
        return ("", i)
#    if data[i].body.startswith("bpy."):
#        return (data[i].body, i)
    else:
#        return getlastoperation(data, i-1)
        return (data[i-1].body, i-1)
    
def CheckAddCommand(data, line = 0):
    name, index = getlastoperation(data)
    macro = GetMacro(name)
    if macro is True:
        return CheckAddCommand(data[ :index], line + 1)
    else:
        return (name, macro, len(data) + line - 1)

def Get_Recent(Return_Bool):
    #remove other Recent Reports
    reports = \
    [
    bpy.data.texts.remove(t, do_unlink=True)
    for t in bpy.data.texts
        if t.name.startswith("Recent Reports")
    ]
    # make a report
    win = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0]
    area = win.screen.areas[0]
    area_type = area.type
    area.type = "INFO"
    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override['window'] = win
    override['screen'] = win.screen
    override['area'] = win.screen.areas[0]
    bpy.ops.info.select_all(override, action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.info.report_copy(override)
    area.type = area_type
    clipboard = bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard
    bpy.data.texts.new("Recent Reports")
    bpy.data.texts['Recent Reports'].write(clipboard)
    # print the report
    if Return_Bool == "Reports_All":
        return bpy.data.texts["Recent Reports"].lines
    elif Return_Bool == "Reports_Length":
        return len(bpy.data.texts["Recent Reports"].lines)
    
Recent = Get_Recent('Reports_All')
name, macro, line = CheckAddCommand(Recent)

print("Message: {}".format(name))
print("Macro: {}".format(macro))
print("Line: {}".format(line))

bpy.data.texts.remove(bpy.data.texts['Recent Reports'])
```

It is mainly a restructure of some [functions](https://github.com/RivinHDH/CommandRecorder2.8/blob/e1e94d7b1b7a17f7b6bec6e2d9e9c450c8066acf/CommandRecorder.py#L61) from the linked addon which most likely seems to do what @batFINGER suggests above to me. If there is a simpler solution/approach please feel free to edit.

Comment: Hmmm I get this error: 

    `IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[-2]: out of range.`

Comment: what is the length of `data` inside the `getlastoperation()` function? Most likely, the error comes from there.

Comment: As I was guessing this is because the log window is empty. Replace `if len(data) < 1:` with `if len(data) <= 1:` and it should work. I also updated the code above. Thanks for the notice ;-).

Comment: That now works perfectly! You were right about the log being empty at first. Now, all the information is copied to the clipboard and I can then paste this into a text file. It would be useful to extend the code so a text file is created that includes the information. That would be even better. Is it possible?

Comment: It is the same approach as in @batFINGERS solution, just add: `filepath = "recent_reports.txt"
with open(filepath, "a") as f:
    f.write(name.as_string())` as you can see we just replace the variable to be saved which in our case is the `name`.